# Access Provider in Class

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a class called `NavigatorRepository` that I am trying to access, `userProvider`. How should I be accessing the userProvider inside the `NavigatorRepository`? I feel like i've tried everything, except the right thing...

Here is a snippet from `NavigatorRepository`

```
final user = Provider((ref) {
  return ref.watch(userProvider.notifier).getUser();
});
...

class NavigatorRepository {

...

  Future<dynamic> _get(
    String path, {
    Map<String, Object?>? queryParameters,
  }) async {
  
    var x = user; <== How do I get this to work?
}
 

}
```

`UserProvider`

```
class UserNotifier extends StateNotifier<User> {
  UserNotifier()
      : super(User(accessToken: '');

  void setUser(User user) {
    state = user;
  }

  User getUser() {
    return state;
  }
}


final userProvider = StateNotifierProvider<UserNotifier, User>((ref) {
  return UserNotifier();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

1. There is now a newer provider for this purpose, [(Async)NotifierProvider](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider):

```dart
final navigatorProvider = NotifierProvider<NavigatorRepository, void>(() {
  return NavigatorRepository();
});

class NavigatorRepository extends Notifier<void> {
  
  @override
  void build() {
    // you can use ref.watch in this method
    User user = ref.watch(userProvider);
  }

  func() {
    // ref is available in any methods of the NavigatorRepository class
    ref.read(...);
  }
```

2. The next method is to pass the `ref` parameter to the class constructor:

```dart
final navigatorProvider = Provider<NavigatorRepository>(NavigatorRepository.new);


class NavigatorRepository {
  NavigatorRepository(this._ref);

  final Ref _ref;

  func() {
    // ref is available in any methods of the NavigatorRepository class
    _ref.read(...);
  }
}
```

3. The following way better expresses the principle of implementing dependencies, but follows against the design patterns in Riverpod:

```dart
final navigatorProvider = Provider<NavigatorRepository>((ref) {
  return NavigatorRepository(
    authService: ref.watch(AuthService),
    settingService: ref.watch(SettingService),
    userService: ref.watch(UserService),
  );
});

class NavigatorRepository {
  UserService({
    required AuthService authService,
    required SettingService settingService,
    required UserService userService,
  })  : _authService = authService,
        _settingService = settingService,
        _UserService = userService;

  final AuthService _authService;
  final SettingService _settingService;
  final UserService _userService;

  func() {
    // simply call the method
    User user = _userService.getUser();
  }
}
```

The idea is that you pass all necessary dependencies immediately to the constructor of your class. In the end, you know for sure that your class-service only depends on the services that are in the constructor.

Note also that I have made all services private to avoid outside access. If you don't need it, make the fields open.

4. You can simply pass the `ref` parameter when calling any method:

```
class NavigatorRepository {
  ...

  Future<dynamic> _get(
    Ref ref,
    String path, {
    Map<String, Object?>? queryParameters,
  }) async {
    var user = ref.read(userProvider);
  }
}
```

Although here you could pass `User user` as a parameter to the method and use it inside. But apparently there can be more such dependencies and then it is easier just to pass `ref`.

Answer (score -1):

Found this thread which covers what I am trying to do.

https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/295#issuecomment-770384596

I needed to pass the ref to my code,

> No, making a global ProviderContainer is a terrible idea. It should
> never be publicly available
>
> Instead, pass a "ref" to your code. You should always be able to
> obtain one.

Comment: That's not good enough. We need you to paste the content from the link.